# How do I create a table from lists of tuples

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to extract values from a list of `Data.Map(Int Int)` using `Map.toAscList` and I want to layout the data in a table, i.e.

```hs
[[(0,10),(1,5)],[(0,20),(1,3)],[(0,30),(1,15)]]
```

becomes

```hs
        0,1   --heading
        10,5  --set 1
        20,3  --set 2
        30,15 --set 3
```

I'm trying to export the data to a .csv file so I can turn it into a chart
what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What if the maps are defined on a different set of keys? E.g. the first one maps 0 to 4 (only), the second maps 1 to 2 (only).

Comment: @chi Yes, this is exactly the difficulty that I am having, each row has a different set of keys so I need to map them each uniquely

Comment: What do you mean by Data.Map(Int Int)? Data.Map.Map Int Int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to my problem was to put the entries back into a map, like so

```hs
collect :: Ord k => [(k,v)] -> Map.Map k [v]
collect [] = Map.empty
collect ((k,v):pairs) = Map.insertWith (++) k [v] $ collect pairs
```

this then allows me to extract them like this

```hs
showTable :: [(Int,[Int])] -> [String]
showTable [] = [""]
showTable ((k,v):pairs) = (show k ++ "$" ++ intercalate "$" (map show v)) : showTable pairs
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a hard problem, just do one thing at a step and you get what you want:

```
let
  heading = map fst (head datas)
  rows = map (map snd) datas
in heading : rows
```

You should notice that there is a lot of implicit constraints to be fullfilled to make this code correct, you may want to add some assertion sentenses.